# How to make activity settings working

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to do very simply App with Android Studio 1.2.1.1  My App should have two activities - main_activity and Settings activity, which is shown when user press left button (i don't know how it is called - menu?) and Settings option appears.

I can't use emulator (I don't know why - there is some problem with HAXModule - I can't turn it on in BIOS (HP BIOS sux) - so I use my Galaxy S Advance device.

I'm using Setup Wizard - Start New Android Project:
[image]

Next I choose Jelly Bean 4.1 (because I have 4.1.2 on my phone)
[image]

Then Blank Activity (Maybe I should use Blank Activity with Fragment?)
[image]

Main Activity no changes:
[image]

Because oF Gradle Issue, I changed charset into UTF-8
[image]

And now, when I run this App - it works - it shows Hello World, and when I press menu button I can see settings, but pressing does nothing....

Let's add SettingsActivity File/New/Activity/Settings Activity. Here I change Hierarchical Parent into MainActivity

[image]

I change the method onOptionsItemSelected:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

And because cannot resolve Intent symbol, I press ALt+Enter to add Intent symbol.

But now when I run it on phone, pressing Setting leads to error: The App is stopped (or sth like this)

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="local.test.testso" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="local.test.testso.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Logcat shows nothing

What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: Post your stack trace (logcat output).  Also post your AndroidManifest.xml.  Your code looks fine.

Comment: Probably, you didn't declare the SettingsActivity in your AndroidManifest.xml, but I can't be sure without looking at it.

Comment: @Jones I didn't do anything to AndroidManifest. I updated the question with AM.xml

Comment: @DanielNugent - no logcat output, AndroidManifest in update

Comment: @SledgehammerPL Everything in your question looks ok.  Honestly, I'm not sure why it's not working for you.  It looks like Android Studio automatically updated your AndroidManifest.xml because you used the wizard to create SettingsActivity, and it looks good.  Your code in your question looks good as well.

Comment: @SledgehammerPL the manifest looks fine, can you post the logcat with the error stack trace?

Comment: Logcat is empty or i don't know how to turn it on

Comment: @SledgehammerPL It can't be empty, everytime the app crashes there will be the message with the reason why it crashed. Anyway, can you show me the SettingsActivity code? Maybe the problem lies there.

Comment: How to turn it on - it is empty. The event log shows 18:26:06 Gradle build finished in 1m 26s 178ms
18:26:39 Session 'app': running but Logcat window has zero chars.

Comment: @Jones maybe DeviceMonitor: Adb rejected connection to client '3325': closed is the problem? I found that my path was wrong, but after fixing it nothing changed - i can adb server-kill and  adb server-start - but still adb rejected connection